# How to display Chinese character?

Tags: 12.04, gedit, chinese

I have a csv file which contains English and Chinese words, in XP I could open it with Notepad++ and it displayed both without problem, but when I went to Ubuntu 12.04 using gedit, it showed Chinese char as bunch of garbage, what should I do to display correctly the Chinese char in csv file?

background:
the csv file is an export file from Ant Movie Catalog, which contains movie titles in English & Chinese, so when I tried to export to .amc format and imported into GCStar, it showed Chinese titles as garbage, the same using XML export, when I tried to export to csv, it worked (the csv file showed Chinese char in XP), but when I tried to open it in Ubuntu 12.04 using gedit, it showed garbage as well, so I have to fix it first before importing into GCStar.

TIA
Michael

Comment: Still looking for an answer? How about the one below?

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following code in terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'BIG5', 'BIG5-HKSCS', 'EUC-TW', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"
```

and the chinese will be displayed successfully.
It works well with traditional Chinese on my 64 ubuntu 12.04.